# Differences between MongoDB Shell Scripting and JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongo-shell

Since this is for a homework assignment I do not want to post my code because it essentially gives a solution. I can post some generic snippets. I am going to start off by saying I am new to javascript and Mongo, and basically learned them in a few hours last night.

Basically I have code that when I paste into the shell, it works perfectly, but when I save it into the database and try to execute it does not work. Here is a basic example.

```
db.system.js.save(
{
   _id: "istrue",
   value: function (x){ 
   if(x == true)
      print("true");
   else
      print("false");
   }
})
```

So if I copy and paste this code and set `var x = true` or `var x = false` first then it works, but if I do this:

```
db.eval("istrue(true);");
```

Then it doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you getting any errors? If so, what are they?

Comment: @icanc: please read the homework tag wiki. Don't ever add it to new questions please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find any documentation on this behavior, but a little testing reveals that your code is running just fine, but either stored functions can't use `print` or the output of `print` goes somewhere other than stdout.  If you `return` strings instead of printing them, you'll see what you would expect.

I suspect the output is going to the MongoDB logs, but I'm not sure where my install put them.

Comment: ok, this sucks because in my actual code I have a bunch of print statements. I guess I have declare a string and append it a bunch of times.